# How to protect equipment from voltage anomalies

Tags: voltage-regulator, ac, ups

My refrigerator makes some short anomalies in electric network in my apartment whenever it starts/stops its compressor. I'm not sure if it's a brief frequency change or voltage drop. I can notice this by hearing loud bang in my guitar amp (when it's turned on). Also I can hear it in my headphones when they're connected to my PC - both desktop and laptop when it's plugged in.

How can I protect my equipment from that?
I have tried line-interactive UPS with AVR ([APC BX950U-GR](https://www.apc.com/shop/nl/en/products/APC-BACK-UPS-950VA-230V-AVR-Schuko-Sockets/P-BX950U-GR#)), but situation stayed the same.
I cannot afford an online UPS.

What kind of equipment can solve my problem?
If that's an AVR, what specification it should have?

Answer (score 0):

Any power interference that shows up in PC and laptop sound, but doesn't reboot those, must be RF radiation.   Power wiring isn't the main problem.
To get RF from a switching refrigerator, you likely have a dirty relay contact, or similar spark-making switch.

A common-mode clip-on choke on the refrigerator power cord might help,
but switch or relay contacts that are sparking are likely to fail soon.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It sounds that you're right. But couldn't find that type of choke. How does it look like? Can you give me a link to some model? Maybe I haven't understood you right, because English is my foreign language and that is technical term.

Comment: @R2-D2 ; language is a problem, there's so MANY names for the devices that it was hard to pick one (but, I've got a bucketful of the hardwares).  Try here <http://a.co/d/0kXsj5X> for a listing (with clumsy names applied)

Comment: I found it! We call it "filter" :) I've put one on the cable, but nothing happened. I've move it to different positions on the cable, and later I've put one more filter on that cable, but nothing has helped. The interference is probably too strong. But thank you for help!

Comment: Just one more thing to try: is there an icemaker, with a metal pipe?  That, too, could act to radiate, and deserves a test application of a filter/ferrite/choke.

Comment: No. There is no icemaker